# I am trying to check if a value isl Resistant in a table from a Form using dlookup

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to lookup a value in a table for a particular patient ID and see whether that patient has the value Resistant. If so then disable a particular button on the form. I tried the following dlookup but it's giving me compiler error:

```vb
If DLookup("Rifampicin", "TableGeneXpert", "[PatientID] = " & Forms.FrmTreatment!PatientID) = Resistant Then
    Me.btnDSTMatch.Enabled = True
Else
    Me.btnDSTMatch.Enabled = False
```

Comment: First guess badly written dlookup change to: if DLookup("Rifampicin", "TableGeneXpert", "[PatientID] = " & Forms.FrmTreatment!PatientID & " AND Rifampicin = Resistant") Then Me.btnDSTMatch.Enabled = True Else Me.btnDSTMatch.Enabled = False

Comment: It is giving error  runtime 2471 The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: 'Resistant'

Comment: assuming "Rifampicin" is a column of String type(?) and "Resistant" is a legitimate value then try putting Resistant in single quotes like this:   " AND Rifampicin = 'Resistant' ")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```vb
If DLookup("Rifampicin", "TableGeneXpert", "[PatientID] = " & Forms.FrmTreatment!PatientID & "") = "Resistant" Then
    Me.btnDSTMatch.Enabled = True
Else
    Me.btnDSTMatch.Enabled = False 
End If
```

Or perhaps directly:

```vb
Me.btnDSTMatch.Enabled = IsNull(DLookup("Rifampicin", "TableGeneXpert", "[PatientID] = " & Forms.FrmTreatment!PatientID & " And [Rifampicin] = 'Resistant'"))
```

To filter on the latest date you can include a *DMax* expression or (the little known option) an *SQL filter*:

```vb
Me.btnDSTMatch.Enabled = IsNull(DLookup("Rifampicin", "TableGeneXpert", "[PatientID] = " & Forms.FrmTreatment!PatientID & " And [Rifampicin] = 'Resistant' And [JournalDate] = (Select Max([JournalDate]) From TableGeneXpert Where [PatientID] = " & Forms.FrmTreatment!PatientID & " And [Rifampicin] = 'Resistant')"))
```

Comment: Is there possible way for that dlookup to take the latest result of the patient based on the date field in that table?

Comment: use dmax instead of dlookup

Comment: Yes, see expanded answer, please.